# Groovy Sql to execute statements in a batch

Tags: sql, groovy, sap-ase

I am using Groovy Sql to fetch results. This is the output from my Linux box. Actually there are 2 statements involved `sp_configure 'number of open partitions'` and `go` see below

```
%isql -U abc -P abc -S support
1> sp_configure 'number of open partitions'
2> go
Parameter Name                 Default     Memory Used Config Value
     Run Value    Unit                 Type
------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------
     ------------ -------------------- ----------
number of open partitions              500        5201         5000
             5000 number               dynamic

(1 row affected)
(return status = 0)
1>
```

I am using groovy code

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:abc:sybase://harley:6011;DatabaseName=support;",dbuname,dbpassword,Driver)
sql.eachRow("sp_configure 'number of open partitions'"){ row ->
        /*println row.run_value*/
    }
```

Is there a way to execute statements in batch?

I am using Sybase

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but you might be able to do:

```
sql.call("sp_configure 'number of open partitions'")
sql.eachRow("go"){ row ->
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969545/why-do-i-keep-getting-object-reference-on-server-while-it-works-fine-on-a-local) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have not actually tried this [yet] but:

```
sql.call("sp_configure 'number of open partitions'")
int[] updateCounts = sql.withBatch({
   sql.eachRow("go"){ row ->
     ...
   }
})

// check your updateCounts here for errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
sql.eachRow("sp_configure 'number of open partitions'"){ row ->
        println row.'Parameter Name'.trim    }
```