# Why do I keep getting Object reference on server while it works fine on a local system

Tags: java, json, groovy, struts

My class objects are not getting converted into json, I think it returns object references, though while executing it locally, it executes perfectly.

Here is the code

```
private def static sql

private static List<ProductAlertsResponse> executeSelection(String query)
{
    List<ProductAlertsResponse> prodAlerts=new ArrayList<ProductAlertsResponse>()
    sql.eachRow(query)
    {
        ProductAlertsResponse prodAlert=new ProductAlertsResponse((String)it.id,(String)it.name,(String)it.description,(String)it.active,(String)it.release_date)
        prodAlerts.add(prodAlert)
    }
    return prodAlerts
}

static main(args) {

    AppProperties.load()
    sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+AppProperties.get("hostname")+":"+AppProperties.get("port")+":"+AppProperties.get("service"), AppProperties.get("username"), AppProperties.get("password"),"oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")

    List<ProductAlertsResponse> sqlResult=executeSelection("select ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,ACTIVE,RELEASE_DATE from productinfo where ACTIVE='A'")

    def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([response: sqlResult])

    String response=json.toPrettyString()
    println "$response"
}
```

This gives me back the following response

```
{
"response": [
    {
        "active": "A",
        "release_date": "2011-09-23 00:00:00.0",
        "id": "1",
        "description": "Test",
        "name": "ABC7"
    },
    {
        "active": "A",
        "release_date": "2012-01-19 00:00:00.0",
        "id": "5",
        "description": "Test1",
        "name": "ABC3"
    },
    {
        "active": "A",
        "release_date": "2011-09-23 00:00:00.0",
        "id": "3",
        "description": "Test",
        "name": "ABC1"
    },
    {
        "active": "A",
        "release_date": "2012-01-19 00:00:00.0",
        "id": "6",
        "description": "Test2",
        "name": "ABC2"
    }
]
}
```

While running it on my server (struts & commons chains) it gives me back the following json response (after removing static)

```
{
"response": [
    "com.est.dxclient.common.ProductAlertsResponse@67f797",
    "com.est.dxclient.common.ProductAlertsResponse@1e8f2a0",
    "com.est.dxclient.common.ProductAlertsResponse@c3d9ac",
    "com.est.dxclient.common.ProductAlertsResponse@7d8bb"
]
}
```

**Note:** I am using groovy 1.8.0

**Update** adding server side code

```
My server side

class GetProductAlertsResponse implements Command {
//Command is import org.apache.commons.chain.Command
    private def sql

    @Override
    public boolean execute(Context ctx) throws Exception 
    {
        AppProperties.load()
        sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+AppProperties.get("hostname")+":"+AppProperties.get("port")+":"+AppProperties.get("service"), AppProperties.get("username"), AppProperties.get("password"),"oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")

        List<ProductAlertsResponse> sqlResult=executeSelection("select ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,ACTIVE,RELEASE_DATE from productinfo where ACTIVE='A'")

        def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([response: sqlResult])

        /*I am trying to debug the code here*/
        println sqlResult.size()

        sqlResult.each{
            println it.getName()
        }

        String response=json.toPrettyString()

        println "Inside commands $response"
        ctx.put(CSMContextParams.response,response)
        return false;

    }
}
```

On the console it prints

```
4
ABC7
ABC3
ABC1
ABC2
Inside commands [
    "com.est.dxclient.common.ProductAlertsResponse@a63599",
    "com.est.dxclient.common.ProductAlertsResponse@156f14c",
    "com.est.dxclient.common.ProductAlertsResponse@9ba632",
    "com.est.dxclient.common.ProductAlertsResponse@bc5245"
]
```

Comment: Hi, does any body have any idea?? Has anyone tried it?

Comment: Can you show your server code?

Comment: @Paul Grime: Hi, I added my server side code.. there is a lot of code so I only added the Command's class `GetProductAlertsResponse`

Comment: You seem to have two lines for `String response=json.toPrettyString()`, is this correct?

Comment: @Paul: I am sorry, actually I am trying other ways too so I had to write the execute function (copy/paste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might help - [Grails JSONBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538423/grails-jsonbuilder).

Maybe your server code uses a different version of Grails, or Grails isn't setup the same between local and server environments.

Comment: I finally managed to find the problem & fix it. It was due to Groovy Library.

In the projects build path I have been using `groovy-all-1.8.0.jar` but in my Package Explorer under Groovy Libraries it had `groovy-all-1.8.4.jar` so on the server side too i changed my lib folder to have `groovy-all-1.8.4.jar` instead of `groovy-all-1.8.0.jar`